# AngularJs : how to do a $watch on a function to evoid the error: $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angularjs-directive, digest

I have a list with items. Each item of a list can be selected. If I select the item, it will be pushed in the cookies.

In my home.html (here I have the list with the items that I can add to cookies)

```
<table class="table" >

        <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in items">                       
            <td><span >{{item.title}}</span></td>
            <td> <button data-ng-click="addToCookies(item)" data-ng-disabled="item.added" class="btn">
    <span data-ng-show="!item[$index].added" class="text-center">Add To cookies</span>
    <span data-ng-show="item[$index].added" class="text-center">Added To cookies</span>
            </button>             
        </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>   
    </table>
```

In page cookies.html I call the getCookiesItem() and the directive :

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-right" data-ng-controller="ctrlItemsList">
        <div data-item-list data-items="getCookiesItem()" ></div>      
    </div>
```

In my controller I did :

//TO ADD ELEMENT SELECTED IN THE COOKIE

```
   $scope.addToCookies = function (item){
                    item.added=true;
                angular.extend($scope.criteria, item);          
                cookiesItems.addItem($scope.criteria);
            }
```

//TO GET ELEMENTS COOKIE  (MAYBE I HAVE TO DO A $WATCH OF THIS FUNCTION)

```
  $scope.getCookiesItem = function (){          
        return  cookiesItems.getItems();

   }
```

In my service I have :

```
Cservices.factory('cookiesItems', ['$cookieStore', function($cookieStore) {   
    var items = [];             
    return {
        addItem: function( itemSelected){
            var array = [];
            if ($cookieStore.get('key') === undefined) {    
                $cookieStore.put('key', []);
            }else{
                array = $cookieStore.get('key');   
            }
            array.push(itemSelected);
            $cookieStore.put('key', array);
        },

        removeItem: function(itemSelected){
            var array = $cookieStore.get('key');
            if(array != undefined){
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ) {
                    if (array[i].id=== itemSelected.id) {                       
                        array.splice(array[i], 1);                      
                    } else {
                        ++i;
                    }
                }
            }
            $cookieStore.put('key', array);
        },
        getItems: function(){
            return $cookieStore.get('key');
        }
```

The elements cookies are print in the following directive:

template :

```
 <table class="table" >     
            <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.title}}</td>                             
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>   
        </table>
```

in the js :

```
iDirective.directive('itemList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            items: '=items'

        }

        templateUrl: ''
    };
});
```

I have the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: [{
```

and when i try to add the 10' element in the cookies I have this error (only 9 element I am able to store): `Cookie '' possibly not set or overflowed because it was too large (4263 > 4096 bytes)! -`

I am not able to resolve it..someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient. `addToCookies` , `getCookiesItem ` , `itemList` , I don't see where you use these. How do you think we suppose to help you?

Comment: @Frumer: I added more code

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could put together a jsfiddle example.

From your code I can see the following issue.
In the ng-repeat section either should use 'items[$index]' or just 'item'.

```
<table class="table" >

    <tr  data-ng-repeat="item in items">                       
        <td><span >{{item.title}}</span></td>
        <td> <button data-ng-click="addToCookies(item)" data-ng-disabled="item.added" class="btn">
<span data-ng-show="!item.added" class="text-center">Add To cookies</span>
<span data-ng-show="item.added" class="text-center">Added To cookies</span>
        </button>             
    </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>   
</table>
```

What is the method addToCookies exactly doing? What is $scope.criteria object? It looks like you always modify and add the same object to the cookieItems.

```
  $scope.addToCookies = function (item){
                item.added=true;
            angular.extend($scope.criteria, item);     // what is $scope.criteria?   
            cookiesItems.addItem($scope.criteria);     // will always the same object added to the cookieItems?
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item);           // why do you have a second list and why you add 'item' and not 'criteria'?
        }
```

Comment: When you click the button, you call the function addToCookies. This method provide  to call the service method (cookiesItems.addItem) to add the item to cookie.